# Javascript to over-ride radio button value

Tags: javascript, forms, radio-button

I'm submitting form results to a script that expects to receive certain values from a set of radio buttons. The form page uses the  for each button to automatically set the HTML "value" attribute for the button. I have no way to set the value attribute independently.

Is there any way to use Javascript to over-ride the value for that field based on which radio button is selected?

Comment: I'm using a landing page generator that doesn't allow me to set, edit, or remove any of the HTML attributes for any form fields. All I can do is add custom Javascript to the page to manipulate the values.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the NAME property from the radio button and assign it to a **hidden field** instead, you could hook up and event handler to set the value of the hidden field on the click of the radio button. This way the hidden field gets passed back instead of the radio button.

Answer (score 0):

Keep on input type to checked="checked"

(OR)

One default input to hidden way

(OR)

Set input to checked=true on before submit in javascript